# PERL Correlation by time in output

Tags: perl, format, correlation, counting

I want ask for some tips. I am working on script parsing some loged data, formate it and than write it on screen. In my case I have 3 Atribute output "Date", "Time", and some "Message". I have log file where some Messages are often occuring. My Idea is. If its possible use Perl for correlations? For Example if I have any event loged 9 times during 5 minutes, output is just 1 message with 9 times count?

My code is this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

#what should be searched in logs
my $regex = 'Error';

my @filtered_arr = ();
my @formated_rows = ();

my $filename = 'report3.txt';

while (<DATA>) {
   if (my $i =/\b(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)\b/ .. /^\n+$/ ) {
      s/\n// if $i !~ /E0\z/; 

       my $logContent = "$_";

  open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die("Could not open file. $!");
  print $fh "$logContent";
  close $fh;
     }
}

  open my $formatedLog, $filename or die "Could not open $filename: $!";

    while( my $line = <$formatedLog>){
      while ($line =~ m/$regex/g) {
         $line =~ m/$regex/;
           push @filtered_arr, $line;
      }
}
  close $formatedLog;

  for my $row (@filtered_arr) {

    my $date = substr $row, 1, 10;  
    my $time = substr $row, 12, 8;
    my $stringDistance = (length $row) - 24;
    my $message = substr $row, 24, $stringDistance -1;

    # creating formated array (For AB)
    push @formated_rows, [$date,";", $time ,";", $message];
  }

# first pass over rows: compute the maximum width for each column
my @widths;
for my $output_row (@formated_rows) {
    for (my $col = 0; $col < @$output_row; $col++) {
        $widths[$col] = length $output_row->[$col] if length $output_row->[$col] > ($widths[$col] // 0);
    }
}

 # compute the format. for this data, it works out to "%-3s %-11s %-6s %-5s\n"
my $format = join(' ', map { "%-${_}s" } @widths) . "\n";

 # second pass: print each row using the format
for my $output_row (@formated_rows) {
    printf $format, @$output_row;
}

__DATA__

[05.09.2015 18:44:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:45:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:46:56] -  Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:47:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:48:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:49:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[06.09.2015 12:46:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404

[06.09.2015 12:47:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404

[06.09.2015 12:48:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404

[06.09.2015 12:48:56] - Oracle Error
 some text about Oracle Error

[06.09.2015 12:49:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404
```

My output looks like this:

```
05.09.2015 ; 18:44:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:44:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:45:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:45:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:46:56 ;  Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:46:56 ;  Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:47:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:47:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:48:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:48:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:49:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
05.09.2015 ; 18:49:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505
06.09.2015 ; 12:46:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:46:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:47:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:47:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:48:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:48:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:48:56 ; Oracle Error some text about Oracle Error
06.09.2015 ; 12:48:56 ; Oracle Error some text about Oracle Error
06.09.2015 ; 12:49:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
06.09.2015 ; 12:49:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404
```

And what I want achieve as output:

```
05.09.2015 ; 18:44:56 ; Error 505 some text about Error 505 ; 12 <- (Means it occur 12 times)
06.09.2015 ; 12:46:56 ; Error 404 some text about Error 404 ; 8
06.09.2015 ; 12:48:56 ; Oracle Error some text about Oracle Error; 2
```

Thank you for any tips Jan.

Comment: No one has any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use a date/time library to make your life easier. [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) is a standard part of the Perl distribution and works well here. Secondly, normalise the times to five minute chunks. Thirdly, create a hash of errors keyed on normalised time and error message.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

# Paragraph mode
$/ = '';

my $format = '[%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S]';

my %errors;

while (<DATA>) {
  # Convert to one line
  s/\n+/ /g;
  my ($time, $error) = split /\s+\-\s+/;
  $time = Time::Piece->strptime($time, $format);
  my $mins = $time->min;
  # Normalise to a five mins
  # By subtracting the correct number of seconds
  $time -= (($mins % 5) * 60) + $time->sec;
  $errors{$time}{$error}++;
}

foreach my $time (keys %errors) {
  foreach my $error (keys %{$errors{$time}}) {
    say "$time ; $error ; $errors{$time}{$error}"
  }
}

__DATA__
[05.09.2015 18:44:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:45:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:46:56] -  Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:47:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:48:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[05.09.2015 18:49:56] - Error 505
 some text about Error 505

[06.09.2015 12:46:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404

[06.09.2015 12:47:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404

[06.09.2015 12:48:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404

[06.09.2015 12:48:56] - Oracle Error
 some text about Oracle Error

[06.09.2015 12:49:56] - Error 404
 some text about Error 404
```

Answer (score 0):

For working with (and comparing) dates, look into [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html), which should be a core module unless you are using a very ancient perl. You can create a `Time::Piece` object by parsing your timestamp string... so once you pull out just the timestamp substring...

```
my $datetime = Time::Piece->strptime( $timestamp, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S' );
```

Then once you have that `Time::Piece` object, you can add and remove seconds, and compare it with other `Time::Piece` objects. You might do something like this to create a cutoff time...

```
$end_time = $datetime;
$end_time += 1 while $end_time->minute !~ /(?:0|5)$/;
```

Given a `$datetime` of `05.09.2015 18:46:56`, `$end_time` will be `05.09.2015 18:50:00`. You can then continue to convert each lines timestamp to a `Time::Piece` object and compare these objects numerically, ie

```
if ( $datetime < $end_time ) {
    # ... increase count for the current logs error
}
else {
    # ... define new $end_time from the current logs timestamp
}
```

Ultimately I leave actual to implementation of these ideas into your script up to you.